# Replace all string if row starts with (within a column)

Tags: r

I am looking to clean up columns that have multiple variations of string by summarizing it via the first region.

i.e if its EMEA | APAC | EMEA, the region should be EMEA (as it starts with it).

i have tried if else, str_replace, starts_with grepl to no avail.

```
bill <- bill%>%
if (starts_with(REGION, "EMEA")) {
  REGION = "EMEA"
} else if (starts_with(REGION, "Asia")){
  REGION = "Asia"
}  else {
   REGION = "Americas"
}
```

argument is not interpretable as logical

Comment: Please provide sample data with `dput(head(bill,n))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier option would be to capture the 'EMEA' or (`|`) 'Asia' at the start (`^`) of the string remove other characters following it

```
bill$REGION <- sub("^(EMEA|Asia).*", "\\1", bill$REGION)
```

Here the characters that are matching inside the `(...)` are captured as a group and in the `replacement`, we specify the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group which is 'EMEA' or 'Asia' depending upon the elements

---

With respect to OP's code, instead of `if/else` (not vectorized), it can be done with `ifelse` or `case_when`

```
bill %>%
    mutate(REGION = case_when(str_detect(REGION, "^EMEA")~ "EMEA",
                              str_detect(REGION, "^Asia") ~ "Asia",
                         TRUE~ "Americas"))
```

Also, the 'starts_with' is used within the tidyverse function environment.  A `base R` option would be `startsWith`

```
 startsWith("EMEA hello", "EMEA")
 #[1] TRUE



starts_with("EMEA hello", "EMEA")
```

> Error in if (ignore.case) match <- tolower(match) : 
>         argument is not interpretable as logical

Comment: this worked straight away. what does the * represent, alongside the \\1. thank you!

Comment: @user11936240. I added some exaplanations.  The `^` is to specify the position which implies the start of the sstring and the `\\1` is the backreference of the captureed group